# Powershell c# module, change promp from a cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

If I run `function prompt {"PS: $(get-date)>"}` in the terminal it changes the prompt.

how can I run this command from a c# cmdlet, for example, what I'm trying is this:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    Host.UI.Write(ConsoleColor.Green, Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor, "function prompt {\"PS: $(get-date)> \"}");
}
```

But it just prints that script in a new line.

(Using PS7.0)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the correct question is "how to run script from a c# cmdlet"

These two lines will run a script that modify the prompt to display the current time.

```
ScriptBlock block = SessionState.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("function prompt {\"PS: $(get-date)> \"}");
SessionState.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(SessionState, block);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a .ps1 file named prompt_change.ps1:

```
function prompt {"PS: $(Get-Date)>"}
```

Then you can run this from powershell console to change your powershell prompt from C#:

```
$code = @'
using System;
namespace TestTest {
  public class Program {
    public static void Main( string[] args ) {
      var ps = PowerShell.Create();
      ps.AddScript(@"Full path of prompt_change.ps1 without double backslashes").Invoke();
    }
  }
}
'@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
Invoke-Expression "[TestTest.Program]::Main()"
```

Comment: This is not what I'm after. I'm trying to run this from a cmdlet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-write-a-simple-cmdlet?view=powershell-7